# Как связать Go и 1C

Tags: golang, 1с

Имеется сервис интернет-магазина, написанный на Golang. Как выгрузить заказы в XML, формировать их. Посмотрел информацию в интернете, практически ничего нет. Каким способом это сделать лучше всего?

Comment: вам стоит конкретизировать вопрос и объяснить ваши цели. В данной формулировке не ясно что вы хотите сделать и зачем

Comment: @SpaceResearcher "выгрузить заказы в XML" недостнточно конкретно?

Comment: @andreymal недостаточно. ",выгрузить заказы в xml", какие заказы, какие поля, какая спецификация . Что такое заказы вообще. Вопрос настолько размытый как будущее на болотах, нужно конкретизировать

Comment: Есть оригинальная документация по 1С и огромная масса информации в Интернете. Странно, что вы ничего не нашли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На 1С нужно поднять вебсервер. Это описано в документации. Потом из приложения интернет-магазина http-клиентом подключаетесь к серверу и обмениваетесь данными в обоих направлениях. Я (с нуля в 1С) по документации 1С и с пощью поиска в Интернете за три часа установил 1С демо, поднял сервер и получил данные в приложение .NET/c#. Там есть тонкости в настройках самого веб-сервера (apache или IIS), нужно поискать отдельно.

Сначала разворачиваете и запускаете сервер, проверяете его работу браузером, а потом уже занимаетесь приложением.

1С предоставляет и альтернативные способы обмена данными с другими системами, но этот самый универсальный. Поддерживает JSON и XML по http.

Answer (score 0):

https://brom.itworks.group/

Там есть расширение для 1С:Предприятие, позволяющее полностью управлять 1С из любого языка программирования - есть готовый клиент для python. Реализовать SOAP клиента на Go не сложно. В той минимальной функциональности что вам необходимо достаточно просто написать 2-3 SOAP запроса.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]